# How to prove $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^ne^{-xa^n}\ne \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-x)^n}{n!(1+a^n)}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Assume that for $x>0$ and $a>1$,$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^ne^{-xa^n},\quad g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-x)^n}{n!(1+a^n)}$$
Regardless of validity, I use Taylor expansion for $e^{-xa^n}$ with respect to $x$, and then exchange the order of both series to get $g(x)$.

However, $f(x)\ne g(x)$. For example, when $a=2$, 
$$f(1)-g(1)=0.0001579\cdots.$$
So why does this kind of circumstance appear ? In other words, why does $f(x)\ne g(x)$ ?

Comment: The  free coefficient in the first series is $\;1\;$ whereas in the second series it is $\;\cfrac12\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio You can obtain that $f(x)\to \frac{1}{2},x\to 0^+$. On the other hand, $g(0)=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Are you really sure that you can  use Taylor expansion for $e^{xa^n}$ to get $g(x)$? It seems impossible to me.

Comment: @mrcntn What I said is that if regardless of validity…

Comment: Cool, so you formally expand the exponential, rearrange the terms and get a geometric-series in some power of $a$, this gives you $g(x)$.. this is the reason of the $(1+a^n)$ denominator in $g(x)$. Nice question, I upvoted it.

Comment: @RocHang The series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^∞(-1)^n\exp(-xa^n)$ converges absolutely since$$\sum_{n=n_0}^∞\mathrm{e}^{-xa^n}\leqslant\sum_{n=n_0}^∞\mathrm{e}^{-Cxn}<+∞$$where $n_0=\left\lceil\dfrac1{a-1}\right\rceil$ and $C=\dfrac{a^{n_0}}{n_0}$.

Comment: @RocHang The limit of $f(x)$ as $x \to 0^+$ does not exist, it is $1/2$ + (something that oscillates).

Comment: OK, thanks very much.

Answer (score 5):

Of course, the "regardless of validity" approach is incorrect; $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n a^{nk}$ doesn't sum to $(1+a^k)^{-1}$ (and in fact diverges) for $a>1$. The interesting question is "why is $f(x)$ still close to $g(x)$?".

An answer may be obtained using [Cahen-Mellin integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform#Cahen%E2%80%93Mellin_integral). For any $c>0$, $$f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi\mathrm{i}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\int_{c-\mathrm{i}\infty}^{c+\mathrm{i}\infty}\Gamma(s)(xa^n)^{-s}\,ds=\frac{1}{2\pi\mathrm{i}}\int_{c-\mathrm{i}\infty}^{c+\mathrm{i}\infty}\frac{\Gamma(s)x^{-s}}{1+a^{-s}}\,ds$$ (this time the convergence takes place), and thus $f(x)$ is equal to the (infinite) sum of residues of the integrand at its poles (which is shown the usual way, by considering the integral along the boundary of $[-N-1/2,c]+2\pi\mathrm{i}[-N,N]/\log a$ and taking $N\to\infty$).

The residue at $s=-n$ (for $n$ a nonnegative integer) is exactly $(-x)^n/(n!(1+a^n))$, but there are also poles at $s=s_n:=(2n+1)\pi\mathrm{i}/\log a$, where $n$ is an integer, and the principal value of $\log a$ is taken: $$f(x)=g(x)+\frac{1}{\log a}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\Gamma(s_n)x^{-s_n}$$ (where again the principal value of $x^{-s_n}=\exp(-s_n\log x)$ is taken). We have $|x^{-s_n}|=1$ for each $n$, but $|\Gamma(s_n)|$ decay rapidly. For $a=2$ and $x=1$, the "remainder" is $(2/\log 2)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\Re\Gamma(s_n)$, and $$\Re\Gamma(s_0)\approx 5.4732\cdot 10^{-5},\quad\Re\Gamma(s_1)\approx-2.258\cdot 10^{-10},\quad\Re\Gamma(s_2)\approx-1.808\cdot 10^{-16},\quad\ldots$$

Comment: Oh, thank you so much.